# Need to join and sum on sql tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, sum

I am trying to learn Microsoft SQL Server and I'm trying to figure out how I can do the following.

I have two tables:

**users**

```
id  fname   lname   username
111 kely    dike    kdike
222 hana    sho     hsho
333 mike    dime    mdime
444 sergi   xan     sxan
```

and

**email_recipient**

```
id  recipient_id    fname   lname
1      222          hana    sho
2      222          hana    sho
3      222          hana    sho
4      333          mike    dime
5      111          kely    dike
6      111          kely    dike
7      444          sergi   xan
8      444          sergi   xan
9      444          sergi   xan
10     444          sergi   xan
```

and what I want to do is to count how many emails each user received, something like this:

```
id  fname   lname  username email_recipient total
111 kely    dike   kdike          2
222 hana    sho    hsho           3
333 mike    dime   mdime          1
444 sergi   xan    sxan           4
```

Could someone please point in the right direction?

Comment: Why microsoft sql? How about ANSI SQL?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

```
SELECT a.id, a.fname, a.lname, a.username, COUNT(*) AS email_recipient_total
FROM users a
INNER JOIN email_recipient b ON b.recipient_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.fname, a.lname, a.username
```

**Result**

```
|  ID | FNAME | LNAME | USERNAME | EMAIL_RECIPIENT_TOTAL |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 111 |  kely |  dike |    kdike |                     2 |
| 222 |  hana |   sho |     hsho |                     3 |
| 333 |  mike |  dime |    mdime |                     1 |
| 444 | sergi |   xan |     sxan |                     4 |
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49409d/1)

Comment: Why did you ask the question if you knew the answer?

Comment: @Bohemian I asked why Microsoft SQL

Comment: @njk Do we need to group them by all `GROUP BY a.id, a.fname, a.lname, a.username` ? 
I tested your fiddle and it works same for `GROUP BY a.id`

Comment: @sansix The fiddle was tested on a MySQL environment. OP is using MSSQL which is ANSI standard.

Comment: @njk so you mean to say "it may produce different result on MSSQL" if one goes with `GROUP BY a.id` only

Comment: `GROUP BY a.id` won't work on MSSQL if you are selecting other columns.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this might have a slightly better performance, but nonetheless, essentially the same answer:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  a.fname, 
  a.lname, 
  a.username, 
  b.email_recipient_total
FROM users a
  INNER JOIN (
      select recipient_id, COUNT(*) AS email_recipient_total
      from email_recipient
      group by recipient_id
    ) b ON b.recipient_id = a.id
```